# react native graphql fetching data from wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, react-native, graphql, fetch

I have a problem exporting data from my wordpress page to my react native application.

my problem is when I need to import the category and the tags of each post. when I map the category to appear in console, it shows "Undefinited"

this is my query on graphql plugin:

```
query MyQuery {
  posts {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        slug
        date
        tags {
          edges {
            node {
              name
            }
          }
        }
        featuredImage {
          node {
            sourceUrl
          }
        }
        categories {
          nodes {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the returned example:

```
{
  "data": {
    "posts": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "cG9zdDoyNjAyNg==",
            "title": "Joven muere al caerle cable de alta tensión en Barahona",
            "slug": "joven-muere-al-caerle-cable-de-alta-tension-en-barahona",
            "date": "2021-07-27T16:24:24",
            "tags": {
              "edges": [
                {
                  "node": {
                    "name": "Muerte"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "featuredImage": {
              "node": {
                "sourceUrl": "https://72.44.48.164/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/energía_electrica.webp"
              }
            },
            "categories": {
              "nodes": [
                {
                  "name": "El País"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
```

this is a console log of the fetch data:

[Imagen posts data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGHoG.png)

and this is my code:

```
console.log(data);
                return (
                    <ScrollView style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        padding: 20,
                        backgroundColor: scheme === 'dark' ? '#151515' : 'white'
                    }} 
                        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    >
                        <View style={styles.welcom}>
                            <Text style={{
                               fontSize:16,
                               fontWeight:'bold',
                               color: scheme === 'dark' ? 'white' : '#151515' 
                            }}>
                                Te mantenemos informado hoy y siempre
                            </Text>
                        </View>

                        {data.posts.edges.map((post, key) => {
                            let url = 'https://images5.alphacoders.com/115/thumb-1920-1150108.png'
                            //console.log(post.node.featuredImage.node.sourceUrl)
                            console.log(post.node.categories.nodes.name);
                            return(
                                <View style={styles.vcontainer} key={key}>                                     
                                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.infocontainer} onPress={() => {
                                        navigation.navigate('Post', {id: post.node.id});
                                    }}>
                                        <Image style={styles.postimg} source={{uri: url}} resizeMode = 'cover'/>
                                        <View style={styles.textcontainer}>
                                            
                                            <View style={styles.termscontainer}>
                                                <Text style={styles.category}>categoria {JSON.stringify(post.node.categories.nodes.name)}</Text>
                                                <Text style={{color: scheme === 'dark' ? 'white' : '#151515' }}>  |  </Text>
                                                <Text style={styles.tag}> tags {post.tags.node.name}</Text>
                                                <Text style={{color: scheme === 'dark' ? 'white' : '#151515' }}>  |  </Text>
                                                <Text style={styles.date}>{Moment(post.node.date).format('D MMM YYYY')}</Text>
                                                    
                                                
                                            </View>
                                            <Text style={styles.title}>{post.node.title}</Text> 
                                            
                                        </View>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>
                            )
                        }
                        )}
                    </ScrollView>
```

and the console.log of data from category:

["Undefined"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myQoV.png)

I need help plis, i've been stuck in this for 1 week

Comment: `...nodes[ {...} ]` > `nodes` is an array > `...nodes[0].name` ... simply log higher object to check structure (array or object)

Comment: @xadm Thanks!!!